# How to set an icon image and a text heading side by side in Bootstrap framework in following scenario?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm using **Bootstrap 2.0.1** framework for my website.

I want to show the icon image and on right side of an icon image I want to show the text. Both should be inline and vertically center aligned. I managed to bring the icon image vertically center align but not able to show the text on right side of this icon image. Now the text is appearing above the icon image. Please help me in resolving this issue.

For your reference I'm putting below my code. I've also added one comment above the code where I'm facing the issue.:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" style="position:fixed">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <!-- Below is the code to show icon image and text side by side. The icon image is of size 54 * 50-->
      <a class="brand" href="index.php"><img style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; margin:auto;" src="new_logo.png"/></a><p>Nice Site</p>
     <div class="nav-collapse">
   </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using `inline` or `inline-block` should suffice.

Comment: @MihaiStancu:Can you please post this as an answer with your style integrated in my code?

Comment: Moved my suggestion to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to position elements on the same row you have 4 options:

1. Position absolute / fixed which is bad because it's not a flexible solution and differences in sizes of either element can make this get out of whack.
2. Floating right/left which is a pretty common solution and it's good enough but it has a small downside -- the height of the floated element behaving differently that expected. This solution is the go-to for positioning bigger content blocks -- it's uncommon for smaller pieces of text.
3. Using inline / inline-block which makes any type of block element such as `p` work as if it was an inline element such as `span` which is the go-to solution for making `a` anchors behave like blocks (buttons) and not like text.
4. Using an actual inline such as `span` which is a more semantic approach because the content is structured according to its role.

Here's an example for 3. and 4.:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" style="position:fixed">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <!-- Below is the code to show icon image and text side by side. The icon image is of size 54 * 50-->
            <a class="brand" href="index.php">
                <img src="new_logo.png"/>
            </a>
            <p style="display: inline-block;">Nice Site</p>
            <span>Nice Site</span>
        <div class="nav-collapse">
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It really worked for me. But the only issue I'm facing is putting the heading vertically center. I've used <h3></h3> instead of <p></p>. Now the heading is vertically top-aligned. How to bring it vertically center aligned?

Comment: Let me check. Normally all you need to do is use `line-height` and `vertical-align`.

Comment: Along with using `vertical-align: bottom` you need to either put the `<img>` inside the `h3` or disable the `h3`s margin-bottom (set it to 0).

Answer (score -1):

Just add `padding-left` to the text (`<p>` tag)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujyrezxb/)

Comment: It's working in fiddle but not in my case. Same is the result.

Comment: -1 because adding a padding is like brooming the trash under the rug. It does solve the main problem but it creates other future problems as well as being a "dirty fix".

Comment: Adding a padding is "dirty"? well, Some of us may have diferent opinions about it, and... "-1" when, in your own words, "It does solve the main problem"...  Anyway fine. Keep that behaviour so you may discourage people to try to help others. Indeed you did it with me.